# How to install dotnet SDK on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, apt-get

I have been following the instructions provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

However, I keep getting the error when I try to run"

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

Specifically it says:

> E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
>   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.4'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.4'

However, doing a `sudo apt search dotnet` results in the package showing up.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: ...but the docs say `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.3` ?

Comment: Did you try the steps at https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu instead?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Should I delete and re-post? The main goal I am trying to do is get a Linux development environment setup for .Net...

Comment: @Aerophilic No. You're on topic.

Comment: @jww You appear to be fostering a misconception about the types of questions that can be asked here. Referring to [the document](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that you posted above, you'll see the following in the very first paragraph. "if your question generally covers… [snip] ***software tools commonly used by programmers***; [snip] … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" I think we can all agree that installing an SDK falls into this bracket.

Comment: ...however, I still think there might be value in asking about this over at https://askubuntu.com or similar.

Comment: I've run the install steps from four different sites. I get the same problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try running this command on your terminal:

```
wget -q packages-microsoft-prod.deb https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Then update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, run the command to install .NET

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Looks like they finally fixed their packages!

Comment: I follow commands but I got this errors. 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.1.4

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.4'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.4'

Comment: Yes! I'd been trying to get this working on my Mint box for days, and no set of instructions I'd found worked. Ubuntu, no problem. Mint?  Problem. This, however, worked. (Mint 18.3)  You rock!

Comment: See my answer below. You need to add the google dns to your etc/rosolv.conf file to see  the packages

Answer (score 6):

Ensure you're running the prerequisite commands also:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
```

```
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
```

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

Comment: For others, under Ubuntu 18.04 you need to run this command: `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'`

and after updating the list of packages, install this package `sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-2.1`

Comment: It worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04 and dotnet-sdk-3.1  Note that you use the following for command for dotnet-sdk-3.1: `sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1`

Answer (score 3):

One reason why apt is unable to locate the packages is that they are not available for your processor architecture. The dotnet core Linux libraries do not support the 32-bit PC (i386, i686), only the 64-bit PC (amd64) are supported. If you happen to have a Ubuntu install of a different architecture, apt-get will report the aforementioned error:

```
Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.2'
```

Check your current architecture with the command:

```
arch
```

If this returns anything else than amd64, you're probably out of luck. Unless you installed a 32-bit PC Ubuntu image on a 64-bit PC. If that's the case, reinstall Ubuntu, using a 64-bit PC (AMD64) install image.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if the deb package to set up the apt repo has some issues. As a quick fix do after installing the ms repo setup package:

```
sudo cp \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list.save \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list

 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

Fix worked on ubuntu 18.04 but seems to be the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The update is missing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing `sudo apt-get update` you may get this error:

```
W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Note that it's not that obvious (it's all the same font color and can be easily overlooked if you don't read everything that gets printed to the console output).

It can be fixed with this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
```

I'm not really sure what it actually does, looks like adding a 3rd party certificate authority or something like that. Any way, after redoing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4` the package can finally be installed without the "couldn't find" errors.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is bit late but I believe act of adding value is never late .

I found these writing links below to be very helpfull and detailed
it is detailed enough about installing the ubuntu on linux and discussing .NET Core releases and versions of Ubuntu they are supported on.

[INSTALL DOTNET CORE LINUX : HOW TO INSTALL .NET CORE ON UBUNTU](https://decatechlabs.com/how-to-install-net-core-on-ubuntu)

It also has link on how to install latest ubuntu 20.04 as well.

[How to Install .NET core 3.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)](https://decatechlabs.com/install-net-core-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa)
[image: .NET Core releases and versions of Ubuntu they are supported on.]

Answer (score 0):

On WSL 16.04 I couldn't resolve the Microsoft or debian server locations. Here were the steps I took:

cd /etc/

sudo chmod 777 resolv.conf

cat resolv.conf (if no 8.8.8.8 for Google dns then follow the next line)

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> resolv.conf

sudo wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/icu/libicu57_57.1-6+deb9u4_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libicu57_57.1-6+deb9u4_amd64.deb

sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-3.1 (change the version number to the one you want)